# Android SQLite condition failed during shift changed

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am working on a application where I am fetching data from SQLite table with a condition. I am getting  correct shift id 1 and 2 during shift A and B but my condition fails in shift C. How can I achieve this ?

Shift timing-

1. **A** = 06:30:00 - 14:30:00
2. **B** = 14:30:00 - 22:30:00
3. **C** = 22:30:00 - 06:30:00

Below is my code -

```
Cursor cursor = db1.rawQuery("SELECT shift_id, shift_name FROM shift_master WHERE start_time <= time('" + time + "') AND  end_time >= time('" + time + "')", null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
       shiftId = cursor.getInt(0);
       shiftName = cursor.getString(1);
       txtShift.setText("Shift" + "-" + shiftName);

       } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
        cursor.close();
```

Comment: How are you storing the time in the database? And what format is it in your app? What is the declaration for the `time` variable?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice There are no date/time types in SQLite.  Therefore, the OP must be storing the data as text, unless it's really being stored a number, in which what is shown is not the actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be the graveyard shift, which starts on one day, at 10:30pm, and wraps around to the next morning, at 6:30am.  One option might be to just add another logical check for the graveyard shift:

```
SELECT shift_id, shift_name
FROM shift_master
WHERE
    (end_time > start_time AND time BETWEEN start_time AND end_time) OR
    (end_time < start_time AND (time > start_time OR time < end_time));
```

This query assumes that your `time` inputs are in the form of `%H:%i%s`, e.g. `12:30:05`.  Since there are no date/time types in SQLite, and these are just stored as text, you would be doing text comparisons anyway, so your inputs should match the shift data you gave in your question.

The logic here is that for a shift which is contained within a single day, the criteria is that the time has to fall inside that shift.  For a shift which wraps around to the next day, then the time has to be either greater than the start of the shift *or* earlier than the end of that shift.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen. The logic you have given was correct and solved my problem.